# Excel absolute values in formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet in the Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppe4rne2qw5lfe2/Matrix_27_v3.xlsx?dl=0

Now, I want to save this Excel sheet in web page(I have excel 2016(office 365) window 8.1). It's working fine and I am able to save it as HTML page.

Now, I need to keep only column A and column S-Y(hyperlinked). The values in column S-Y are reference values from column B-R.

Example: Currently, in the excel file

```
Cell S2  =HYPERLINK(K2,C2)
```

Though, I want it to be like

```
Cell S2= HYPERLINK("http://bit.ly/1Mgsaf2",0)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I have converted column S-Y as hyperlinked by using a VBA routine in which you have to select the range and then run the code. I have uploaded file to dropbox. please see whether it meets your requirements. <https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m6r0geith0zvzi/Matrix_27_v3_13102015.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: @skkakkar - How does this help future viewers with a similar problem?

Comment: @jeeped I feel sorry I have not correctly understood the requirements. I wish to try seriously to reach your competence level but I still find a long road ahead before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in `AA2` in your sample file is:

```
=HYPERLINK(S2,C2)
```

You can use following approach to save `S2` and `C2` as constants:

- Enter in `AA2`:

  `="HYPERLINK(""" & S2 & """," & C2 & ")"`
- Drag to fill all required cells (`AA2:AG28`).
- Copy `AA2:AG28` and paste in the same place as values.
- Select `AA2:AG28` and replace
  `HYPERLINK` with `=HYPERLINK`

Comment: it doesnt work for me. When I drag, it copies the same to all cells. Would it have all these double quotes

Comment: @user1631306 Please see the the edit, fixed a typo (missing `&`). Formula result should be `HYPERLINK("http://bit.ly/1Mgsaf2",0)`

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlink function requires a link location and a friendly name.
For the link location, use the address function to reference the location where the link is being stored

Cell S2: `=HYPERLINK((ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(K2))),C2)`

Edit:
The reason `Hyperlink(K2,C2)` returns #Value is that K2 references a string stored in K2, not the location of K2.  This is why you need the address function.

Comment: but again its depending on K and C cells. I need the hyperlink with absolute real values. So, if I remove the columns B-R, the hyperlink function wont break.